# Referencing a cell for range in an excel sum

Tags: vba, excel

I am producing a spreadsheet in which some costs are being assigned either 0 or 1 based on a condition, as below;

```
Range("V12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(T12 < 50000000, 1, 0)"
Range("V12").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("V12:V511"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("V12:V511").Select
Calculate
```

The line `Range("V12:V511").Select` starts at V12 but I need the final cell to change based on the number placed in cell U3. I'm not sure how to do this, but in essence I want to be able to write something along the lines of `Range("V12:VRange("U3").Value - 1").Select` so that the value of cell U3 is used in this range.

Also, I want to sum these 0s and 1s over that range but am not sure how to dynamically change the limits of a sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range expects a string so we just need to concatenate the value from U3 with the rest of the address string.

All those line can be replaced with:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("V12:V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3")-1).Formula = "=IF(T12 < 50000000, 1, 0)"
```

Or if your prefer R1C1 notation:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("V12:V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3")-1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2] < 50000000, 1, 0)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Will the same thing work if I'm producing a sum over all of those cells?

Comment: to sum them at the bottom: `ActiveSheet.Range("V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3").Formula = "=SUM(" & ActiveSheet.Range("V12:V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3")-1).Address(1,1) & ")"` @Jahambo99

Comment: Excel didn't seem to like that.

Comment: forgot a closing `)` : `ActiveSheet.Range("V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3")).Formula = "=SUM(" & ActiveSheet.Range("V12:V" & ActiveSheet.Range("U3") - 1).Address(1, 1) & ")"` @Jahambo99